# HasForeignKey relationship through a Complex Type property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have two complex types:

```
public class ProductItemIdentifier
{
    public Guid Product_Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}

public class AuctionItemIdentifier
{
    public Guid Auction_Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a entity type:

```
public class Comment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public ProductItemIdentifier ProductItem { get; set; }
    public AuctionItemIdentifier AuctionItem { get; set; }

    #region Navigation

    public virtual Product Product { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Auction Auction { get; protected set; }

    #endregion
}
```

And here is the `Configuration`

```
public class CommentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Comment>
{
    HasKey(p => p.Id);

    HasOptional(p => p.Product).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductItem.Product_Id).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    HasOptional(p => p.Auction).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => new { p.AuctionItem.Auction_Id }).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Basically i am trying to create a foreign key through a Complex Type property (and doesn't work).

The error i get is:

```
The properties expression 'p => p.ProductItem.Product_Id' is not valid. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.
```

Is there any way to create the relationship *without* adding the Foreign Key columns to the `Comment` entity directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. The exception has said that explicitly.

> The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'

It has to be a simple property.

```
public class Comment
{
    ...

    public Guid Product_Id { get; protected set; } // simple property
    public virtual Product Product { get; protected set; }
}
```

Configuration.

```
HasOptional(p => p.Product)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.Product_Id) // satisfies the C#: 't => t.MyProperty'
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And marking the `ProductItemIdentifier` class with `[ComplexType]` won't help either.

Answer (score 0):

my solution was to create some dummy objects

```
public Guid AuctionItem_Auction_Id 
        {
            get { return AuctionItem.Auction_Id; }
            set { AuctionItem.Auction_Id = value; }
        }

    [ForeignKey("AuctionItem_Auction_Id")]
    public virtual Auction Auction { get; protected set; }
```