# Is it possible to use an owned type for many-to-many relations?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

In Entity Framework Core version 2.2 or 3.0, is it possible to use owned/complex types in such a way that this kind of configuration is possible:

```
public class Product {

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public ProductProperties Properties { get; set; }
}

public class ProductProperties {

       public List<ProductSize> Sizes { get; set; }
}

public class Size {

       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSize {

       public int ProductId { get; set; }
       public Product Product { get; set; }

       public int SizeId { get; set; }
       public Size Size { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSize>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Product)
                .WithMany(x => x.Properties.Sizes)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSize>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Size)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.SizeId);
```

The error message which is seen for this kind of approach usually ends up in:

```
'x => x.Properties.Sizes' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a simple property access: 't => t.MyProperty'
```

An earlier found answer is almost exactly matching my question, but this was posted in 2013. By the time it was almost certainly not possible.

[HasForeignKey relationship through a Complex Type property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136638/hasforeignkey-relationship-through-a-complex-type-property?newreg=471d3a533ba2473faa2e3c74cdbae230)

The sources on Microsoft are only giving examples for creating an entity with the complex type itself, not for creating relationships between them.

Answer (score 2):

### The cause of the issue

In your sample code it's quite clear there is no specific Many to Many relation. To make my argument a bit more convincing what follows is a model of your entities and their relations:

[image]

### The new class structure

For a Many to Many relation to work in EF the product and size tables need to have an implicit relation with each other through a singular junction table. In my proposed solution I've chosen the ProductProperty table. There I've added the fields from the productsize junction table:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class ProductProperty
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int SizeId { get; set; }
    public Size Size { get; set; }
}

public class Size 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

### The functions

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductProperty>()
    .HasKey(pp => new { pp.ProductId, pp.SizeId });

modelBuilder.Entity<ProductProperty>()
    .HasOne(pp => pp.Product)
    .WithMany(p => p.Properties)
    .HasForeignKey(pp => pp.ProductId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ProductProperty>()
    .HasOne(pp => pp.Size)
    .WithMany(p => p.Properties)
    .HasForeignKey(pp => pp.SizeId);
```

### Additional advice (EDIT)

Make the "Size" class a generic property class. This way the Many-to-Many relation won't get broken and querying will also be very easy:

```
public class Property
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PropertyType propType { get; set; }
    public string propValue { get; set; }
}

public enum PropertyType
{
    Size,
    Fontsize,
    ...
}
```

As a final argument this change will make it easier to change existing properties or add new ones

### Sources

1. https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is indeed the result of me removing the complex type 'ProductProperties'. But the reason why I have created that complex type, is because there are like 5 different product properties in there. I tried to clean/refactor my code to avoid having long constructors in the Product class. Maybe it is more clear now?

Comment: @Faegav check my advice in the answer

Comment: Even though I appreciate your effort, but it is not a direct answer on my question. Since I have my reasons to design it in the way it is designed. Just for your info; if I would follow your approach, I will not be able to handle all the different properties. The case is rather complex and size is the easiest property I named. Therefore I am mostly interested on the possibility to include a complex type (1 on 1) in ef core and later on use a property inside that type in a relationship. (Also not all properties should be available for all product 'types')

Answer (score 0):

You can check the owned entity types released in 2019 [Check documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)

An example from the link is the following:

```
public class Distributor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<StreetAddress> ShippingCenters { get; set; }
}
```

The owns many function should help you like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Distributor>().OwnsMany(p => p.ShippingCenters, a =>
{
    a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("OwnerId");
    a.Property<int>("Id");
    a.HasKey("Id");
});
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have followed this documentation but unfortunately it doesn't cover the situation of a many to many relationship. Since for EF core we will need to create a junction table. The situation you described is something I have done for the 'Product' entity itself.